# Need a Rest API which should provide Sever monitoring information?

Tags: api, rest

I need a server monitoring REST API  which should provide the below points. can anyone suggest which one is best? I have found some tools like Nagios, Zabbix and Grafana but not sure they will provide Rest API.

```
     1)Server Response time monitoring
     2)Ping monitoring
     3)Port monitoring
     4)Graph event presentation & Logs APIs?
     4)CPU, Harddisk, memory, Apache and Monitoring, etc.
```

Purpose of required API

This API will integrate the A application and gathering information from the C application then we can consolidate represent the custom graph in A application as per JSON result.

Any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Both Nagios and Zabbix do actual data collection, but Grafana only visualizes the data so you'll be looking at the former for this API. Both have a JSON API:

- https://www.nagios.org/ncpa/help/2.2/api.html
- https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/api